# Exhaustiveness check in typeclasses for promoted types

Tags: haskell, typeclass, non-exhaustive-patterns, type-promotion

I have promoted type `Nat = Suc Nat | Zero` and I want to make a typeclass `class C (a :: Nat) b`. Is there a way to convince GHC that `instance C Zero b` and `instance C (Seq x) b` covers all cases and therefore I don't need to explicitly declare `C` as a constraint whenever I use the class' methods. Here is some code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
-- Some of these may not be necessary for the particular snippet.

data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat
-- TypeApplications, I know. I am traditional.
data NProxy :: Nat -> * where
  NProxy :: NProxy n

class C (a :: Nat) b where
  f :: NProxy a -> b -> Maybe b

instance C Zero b where
  f _ _ = Nothing
instance C (Suc a) b where
  f _ = Just
-- instance C n b where
--   f = error "This should not have been reached using GetNum."


class C1 a where
  f1 :: a -> Maybe a

instance C1 a where
  f1 = Just

type family GetNum a :: Nat where
  GetNum Char = (Suc Zero)
  GetNum Int = Suc (Suc Zero)
  GetNum [x] = Suc (GetNum x)
  GetNum a = Suc Zero

-- Error:
-- • No instance for (C (GetNum a) a) arising from a use of ‘f’
-- • In the expression: f (NProxy :: NProxy (GetNum a)) x
--   In an equation for ‘noGreet’:
--       noGreet x = f (NProxy :: NProxy (GetNum a)) x
noGreet :: forall a . a -> Maybe a
noGreet x = f (NProxy :: NProxy (GetNum a)) x

-- This one works fine though.
dumb :: a -> Maybe a
dumb = f1
```

Edit: A related question would be, given the commented out instance if `C`, why is it when I say `noGreet "hi"` to the repl I get an exception and not `Just "hi"`.

Comment: No, because all types are inhabited by stuck type families, so the claim that the kind `Nat` is inhabited only by `'Z` and `'S n` where `n :: Nat` is patently false - `Any :: Nat` and `Any Any :: Nat`, ad infinitum. Furthermore, the need for the explicit constraint could never go away - the constraint is what is actually allowing you to do type level computation. `dumb` works because you have an instance `C1 a` for every type `a` without any constraint on that type.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your answer. So is there a way to trick the type system using IncoherentInstances (see edit)?

Comment: You get an exception because `noGreet` contains a type error, so `noGreet anything` will always be a type error as well. `IncoherentInstances` doesn't have any clearly defined semantics, so you shouldn't expect it to be of any help, ever.

Answer (score 4):

```
noGreet :: forall a . a -> Maybe a
```

Parametricity says the only definable values of this type are things like

```
noGreet x = Just x
noGreet x = Nothing
noGreet x = undefined
noGreet x = x `seq` Just x
...
```

We can't make any choices that depend on the type `a`, like "`Nothing` if `a` is `Char` otherwise `Just x`".

"Tricking the type checker" is a red herring, since what is preventing you from writing such a function is not the type checker, but the fact that information about the type `a` is simply not available at all at runtime.

---

When you used `IncoherentInstances` in

```
noGreet :: forall a . a -> Maybe a
noGreet x = f (NProxy :: NProxy (GetNum a)) x
```

the compiler had to choose which `C` instance to use for the call to `f`, since there is no context provided in the type of `noGreet`. Naturally the only one that applied was

```
instance C n b where f = error "This should not have been reached using GetNum."
```

as the other two instances are too specific to use when we know nothing about `a`.